My leaflet map doesn't load in my android webview app
I am using a webview to load a leaflet map with a marker on it. Everything is behaving as expected, but i can't see the map when my log statement say it is supposed to be loaded. I know the code works because if I load the html file in a browser I can see the map and I know that the webview works because I can see the simple hello world text when I load the html file with it. And I know that the javascript works , because i added "document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";" and the background is blue. I think it has to do with the layout, but I have been playing with it a lot and the map never appears.
Here is my composable code for my webview

import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController

//


@Composable
fun LeafletWebViewMapScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    googleMapsScreenViewModel: GoogleMapsScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Log.d("tag2", "Composable triggered!")
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            WebView(context).apply {
                Log.d("WebView", "WebView is being initialized")
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

//                settings.domStorageEnabled = true // Enable DOM storage for web apps
//                settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT // Ensure proper caching
//
//                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true // This enables web storage for the JS script
                settings.allowContentAccess = true // Allows WebView to access external content
                settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                settings.useWideViewPort = true

                WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)

                // Set a custom WebViewClient to capture errors and log them
                webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                    override fun onReceivedError(
                        view: WebView?,
                        request: android.webkit.WebResourceRequest?,
                        error: android.webkit.WebResourceError?
                    ) {
                        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                        Log.e("tag2", "Error loading page: ${error?.description}")
                    }

                    // This is for older versions of Android (before API 23)
                    override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, errorCode: Int, description: String?, failingUrl: String?) {
                        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl)
                        Log.e("tag2", "Error loading page: $description")
                    }
                }

                // Load the HTML file from assets
                try {

                    Log.d("WebView", "URL loaded: file:///android_asset/leaflet_map.html")

                    loadUrl("file:///android_asset/leaflet_map.html")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    // Log any errors that occur during the WebView setup
                    Log.e("tag2", "Error setting up WebView: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() // Full screen WebView
    )
}

and here is the html file. The map doesn't show, but the javascript work because i get the console messages in my logcat and the screen is blue. I can also see  the Hello World one above the other centered at the top of my screen.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Leaflet Map</title>

    <!-- Include Leaflet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <style>
        /* Ensure the map takes half the height of the screen */
        #map {
            height: 50vh; /* 50% of the viewport height */
            width: 100%;  /* Full width */
        }

        /* Flexbox to center the content vertically and horizontally */
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column; /* Stack items vertically */
            justify-content: flex-start; /* Align items at the top */
            align-items: center; /* Center content horizontally */
            margin: 0; /* Remove default margin */
            padding: 0;
            height: 100vh; /* Full height of viewport */
            text-align: center; /* Center text */
        }

        /* Style the <h1> tags */
        h1 {
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<div id="map"></div>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
<script>
    // You can perform other JS operations here, like DOM manipulation, etc.
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue"; // Change background color
</script>
<!-- Include Leaflet JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<script>
    // Your JavaScript code that will run on page load
    console.log("Hello from JavaScript!");



    try {
        // Initialize the map and set its view to a specific latitude/longitude and zoom level
        var map = L.map('map').setView([37.7749, -122.4194], 13);  // San Francisco coordinates

        // Log success if map is initialized
        console.log("Map initialized successfully!");

        // Add OpenStreetMap tile layer to the map
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        // Add a marker at the specified location
        var marker = L.marker([37.7749, -122.4194]).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup('<b>San Francisco</b><br>Welcome to SF!').openPopup();
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any error that occurs during map initialization
        console.error("Error initializing the map:", error);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>



When I run the app, I can see the text field "Text(text = "Loading locations...")" and then it switches to a blue screen with both "Hello World" showing at the top of my screen, but no map. I was expecting a map, like the one I see when loading the file in the web browser, with a marker in san francisco.
I tried with the google map javascript api and I have the same exact problem.
So my question is how can i make the map show in my webview android app?
I think it has to do with the layout, but I am not good with html/css or javascript for that matter
